blazor webassembly local storage empty on application restart
I use Local Storage in my Blazor application, and when opening/closing my browser it saves perfectly. But when I restart my application, my Local Storage suddenly becomes empty. Any ideas?
I tried looking up StackOverflow and Google for possible solutions, but didn't find anything useful sadly... I hope some of you can help
Code to save:
    string? storage = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("cart");
    List<WarehouseItem> orderesItems = new();
    if (storage == null)
    {
        orderesItems.Add(new()
        {
            Id = warehouseItems[0].Id,
            WarehouseId = warehouseItems[0].WarehouseId,
            ItemId = itemId,
            Quantity = 1
        });

        string serializedItem = JsonSerializer.Serialize(orderesItems);
        await localStorage.SetItemAsStringAsync("cart", serializedItem);

Code to load:
string? storage = await _localStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync("cart");
if (storage != null)
{
  var storedValue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<WarehouseItem>>(storage);
  CartCount = storedValue.Sum(x => x.Quantity);
}

(Don't mind the missing } tags, they do get closed)

Could you edit ur post with a piece of code as to how you're currently handling ur saving and how ur database is setup?

@Rowin there you go!

Okay but how are you configuring ur local storage? Are you using any form of local database? If not, you might need to check ur browser settings and make sure that theres nothing enabled regarding "clear data on exit" or something along those lines. You could also be facing some storage limitations.

I'm not using anything else than just the Local Storage... I will check up on my browser settings, tho I'm pretty sure nothing like that is enabled... But thanks!

Are you using ProtectedlocalStorage  in  blazor  webassembly application? It relies on ASP.NET Core Data Protection and is only supported for server-side Blazor apps.

Update: Found the issue!
When running the application it automatically opens up Chrome, but in some sort of incognito state, which it doesn't save Local Storage in. SO! To fix this, I simply open Chrome myself, and that was it's logged in to my account :)
